# Отправка сообщения с python aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def send_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'hi there', entities=greet_kb,)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hi!\nI'm EchoBot!\nPowered by aiogram.")
```

Использую кнопку, хочу чтобы при нажатии бот отвечал определенный текст но он на любое дейстивее отправляет один и тот же ответ 'hi there' даже для команды /start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в декоратеоре @dp.message_handler() не указали аргументы, обозначающие при каких условиях будет срабоатывать функция send_welcome, из-за этого он у вас срабаотывает каждый раз на любое сообщение. Если же вы хотите чтобы бот на команду /start и /help отвечал "Hi!I'm EchoBot!Powered by aiogram.", а на любые другие сообщения "hi there", вам нужно поменять местами функции.
Вот небольшой код-пример:

```
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import logging

# Initalialization API token for work with Telegram Bot
API_TOKEN = "BOT TOKEN HERE"

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_cmd_message(message: types.Message):
    keyboard_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    press_btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Press ME!', callback_data= 'press')
    keyboard_markup.row(press_btn)
    await message.reply("Hi!\nI'm EchoBot!\nPowered by aiogram.", reply_markup=keyboard_markup)

@dp.message_handler()
async def send_message(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.reply("Hi there!")

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'press')
async def about_bot_message(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer('Ты нажал на кнопку!', True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

[image: TEST BOT]

RTFM и Удачи!

Comment: Возможно ли в декораторе ввести условие нажатия кнопки?

Comment: Ммм, тип чтобы на нажатии Inline кнопки срабатывала функция? Можно, `@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'press')`